# how to set base url in cake php 3 in config/app.php file and get that url in all view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i would like to set base 'url' like "codeigniter" and that can be access in all views.  I want to get full url like "http://localhost/somepath"

Comment: And what have you tried so far and which problems were you faced with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't need to do that, as the `Helpers` in Cake do that automatically.

For example, if your app is under http://localhost/somepath, creating a link like this

```
echo $this->Html->link('home', '/');
```

will automatically point to http://localhost/somepath

Links to actions work the same way:

```
echo $this->Html->link('login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
```

will automatically point to http://localhost/somepath/Users/login

And if you do need to get the url anywhere else than in a view, you can do it like this:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

$path = Router::url('/', true);
```

Comment: $path = Router::url('/', true); that give error what can i do am beggner in cake php   Error: Class 'Router' not found

Comment: That's Cake3, you need to import the class. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3 You can define "BASE_URL" constant in

`yourAppFolder/config/paths.php as`

`define('BASE_URL', 'www.yoursite.com/');`

and use `BASE_URL` anywhere in your project.